# Cannot access an API endpoint using python

Tags: python

I am very new to programming and have been experimenting with accessing data through short python scripts to get my head around how these work.

It has been mostly fine until I decided to use this API (http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/help) which data I actually have a need for.

I would like to access the BusinessTypes endpoint so have been running the following in python 3:

```
import requests

url = 'http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/BusinessTypes'
parameters={'x-api-version':2,'accept':'text/json','content-type':'text/json'}

response = requests.get(url,params=parameters)
```

which returns a 404 status code, and I understand that because pasting the url in my browser tells me the API does not exist.

What I am left clueless about is how to access this "BusinessTypes" endpoint, or any other endpoint for that matter, because my reading of the API documentation tells me this is how I am supposed to access it.

Any help very welcome!

Comment: Does the curl on the same URL + URI work?

Comment: According to the page you linked to, the URL should be `http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/BusinessTypes/{pageNumber}/{pageSize}`, but the URL you're using doesn't match that pattern, hence the error.

Comment: You need to send a header (not parameters) and as @ForceBru has said, use the correct endpoint, eg: `requests.get('http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/BusinessTypes/1/10', headers={'x-api-version': 2}).json()` returns stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this code here should work. If you want to get all the business types you can simply use the url. If you need to page through them you can use the endpoint that specifies the page.

So the issue with your code is that you provided `x-api-version` as a parameter and not a header which is what the api endpoint expected.

```
import requests


page = 1
page_size = 10

url = 'http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/BusinessTypes'
url_with_page = url + '/{}/{}'.format(page, page_size)
headers = {'x-api-version': 2}

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
resp_with_page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```